# OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer python3?

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

I am trying to write a program to solve this pattern and get the value in **nth**  position(**n varies from 1 to 10^5**)

**1,2,7,20,61,182...**[Reference](https://oeis.org/A015518)

I was able to write a function to do that. But keep getting

`OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`

error for larger **n** input occurs in **py3**.
But it works fine in **py2**.

```
   def getPattern(n):
    total = 2
    tmptotal = 1
    count = 2

    if(n == 1 or n == 2):
        print(n)
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if(count == 2):
                total = (total + (total/2))*2 + 1
                count = 1

            else:
                total = (total + ((total-1)/2))*2
                count = 2
                tmptotal = total
        return int(total)

    n =int(input())
    print(getPattern(n))
```

So, I hoping to solve this error in py3 env.

Comment: your code worked for me, i just change the `if __name__ == '__main__':` to `def function():` and call it at the end, You code do not have any issue!

Comment: For which value of n,  the output is infinite?

Comment: What where the insights from your debugging so far?

Comment: @backdor for n > 500 or so, I've updated the question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 `/` is float division so your `total` variable is made into a float. The equivalent code for your python2 code in python3 is this:

```py
def getPattern(n):
    total = 2
    tmptotal = 1
    count = 2

    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        print(n)
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if count == 2:
                total = (total + (total // 2)) * 2 + 1
                count = 1

            else:
                total = (total + ((total - 1) // 2)) * 2
                count = 2
                tmptotal = total
        return total  # No cast needed

n = int(input())
print(getPattern(n))
```

```sh
$ python3 a.py
1000
330517704870201659222613814938036091491355508188037041916230092056707149336676224885194578462652015490977444424218145588987738645525154727966335681314488418506905056299580200969503693557241210318597600029397154510282236953905773609515391543263521668622626544531370086101386763599259723954366342063729034055207567140944645572557104099576971974229639101021224734402343310542961589984673879191254735147027265106522417859716025703587596412186791458002653591533043275692225713805000
$ python2 a.py
1000
330517704870201659222613814938036091491355508188037041916230092056707149336676224885194578462652015490977444424218145588987738645525154727966335681314488418506905056299580200969503693557241210318597600029397154510282236953905773609515391543263521668622626544531370086101386763599259723954366342063729034055207567140944645572557104099576971974229639101021224734402343310542961589984673879191254735147027265106522417859716025703587596412186791458002653591533043275692225713805000
```